Angular logger keep typescript line number
Implementing a custom logger service for Angular 17. Now I want to keep track of the line number of where the service has been called.
Here is my code for retrieving the caller inside the service:
const stack = new Error().stack;
const stackArray = stack?.split('\n') || [];
const callerLine: string = stackArray[3].trim(); 

When I now console.log(stack) the output contains the typescript files with correct line numbers.

But after the .split() the callerLine string shows the javascript position.

Why is this happening?

You can view the actual source files from your disk. What you are seeing is virtual path created by angular. Offcouse for security reasons.
You can turn off sourceMap in angular.json to get exact path but it will expose all the code in production.
